# Merge List of arrays into single array

Tags: python

I have couple of json files in which I want to merge arrays based up on Field number and write into a single json file. I want to do this in python. Can some one please help me here?  Sample input and output are provided below.

File 1:

```
{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950}
{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951}
{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950}
{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951}
```

File 2:

```
{"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":13}]}
{"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":14}]}
{"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":1}]}
{"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":3}]}
```

Final Output :

```
{{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950}, {"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951},{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":13},{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":14}}

{{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950}, {"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951},{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":1},{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":3}}
```

Regards,
Pks

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @PedroMaia I am a SQL developer. Very new to python. So I am not sure where to start with this. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input files and expected output are not valid json.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: Actually your output is not a json but a `set` which doesn't exists in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import itertools we will need this later

```
import itertools
```

The data:

```
file1 = 
[{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950},
 {"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951},
 {"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263950},
 {"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":2,"Activity_list_number":6263951}]


file2 = [{"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":13}]},
         {"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086752,"Activity_code":14}]},
         {"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":1}]},
         {"ListFieldActivityConnect":[{"Field_number":1086754,"Activity_code":3}]}]`
```

First, get rid of the 'ListFieldActivityConnect' key in file2 to get to the list of subfields that we want.

```
file2 = [val['ListFieldActivityConnect'] for val in file2]
```

We are going to fill a dictionary where each key is the "Field_number" and each value is a list of entries that have the corresponding "Field_number".

```
output_dict = dict()
```

Iterate over the combination of the two data sets and populate the output dict. Note, I am using itertools on file2 because it is a list of lists and I want to flatten it.

```
for entry in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(file2)) + file1:
    field_number = str(entry['Field_number'])
    if field_number not in output_dict:
        output_dict[field_number] = [entry]
    else:
        output_dict[field_number].append(entry)


print(list(output_dict.values()))
```

Results in:

```
[[{'Field_number': 1086752, 'Activity_code': 13}, {'Field_number': 1086752, 'Activity_code': 14}, {'Field_number': 1086752, 'Activity_code': 2, 'Activity_list_number': 6263950}, {'Field_number': 1086752, 'Activity_code': 2, 'Activity_list_number': 6263951}], 
 [{'Field_number': 1086754, 'Activity_code': 1}, {'Field_number': 1086754, 'Activity_code': 3}, {'Field_number': 1086754, 'Activity_code': 2, 'Activity_list_number': 6263950}, {'Field_number': 1086754, 'Activity_code': 2, 'Activity_list_number': 6263951}]]
```